# Go modules without remote repository?

Tags: go, multi-module, go-modules

I'm trying to get Go modules working without involving a remote repository.

`src` is a local directory that contains all my projects, also projects that are written in other languages than Go. For simplicity I have only show the two directories relevant for my question:

```
src
 ├── client
 │   ├── go.mod
 │   └── main.go
 └── lib
     ├── go.mod
     └── lib.go
```

The `go.mod` files are created by running the command `go mod init client` in `src/client` and `go mod init lib` in `src/lib`.

**src/client/main.go:**

```
package main

import "lib"

func main() {
    lib.Hello()
}
```

**src/lib/lib.go:**

```
package lib

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}
```

What I'm trying to do is using the library lib.go in my main.go, but no matter what I put in the import path, this error is shown:

```
main.go:3:8: package lib is not in GOROOT (/usr/lib/go/src/lib)
```

Go version is `go1.14.3`

*How do I correctly import Go code from local folders?*

Comment: There's some info here about using a local file path in go.mod: https://medium.com/@adiach3nko/package-management-with-go-modules-the-pragmatic-guide-c831b4eaaf31 (in the "Substitute Imported Modules" section). Hope that helps.

Comment: [Can I work entirely outside of VCS on my local filesystem?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem)

Comment: Use the [replace](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive) directive.

Comment: 1. You should never use an import part like "lib" or "foo/bar" for any of your packages. Such types of import paths should be reserved for the stdlib. 2. You module name should be something like "whatever.you.like/some/folder" 3. A replace directive in the go.mod lets you do whatever you like. 4. The best advice is: Stick to How to Write Go Code and do not try to be clever and do not try do mimic what you might be used from other languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `replace` directive.

Project structure:

```
root
 ├── client
 │   ├── go.mod
 │   └── main.go
 └── lib
     ├── go.mod
     └── lib.go
```

`go.mod` of `root/lib` module:

```
module github.com/owner/root/lib

go 1.13
```

`go.mod` of `root/client` module:

```
module github.com/owner/root/client

go 1.13

require github.com/owner/root/lib v0.0.0

replace github.com/owner/root/lib => ../lib
```

> This is terrible, do you really have to do this for every import if
> there is no VCS?

No. [replace](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) directive replaces the contents of a specific version of a module and includes packages that belong to substitute module.

```
root
 ├── client
 │   ├── go.mod
 │   └── main.go
 └── lib
     ├── utils
     │   └── util.go
     ├── libs
     │   └── lib.go
     └── go.mod
```

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/owner/root/lib/utils"
    "github.com/owner/root/lib/libs"
)

func main() {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

assuming code is for your own use only and won't be published

from your src (or root) directory:

```
$ go mod init <project_name>
```

use the path from the root when you want to import modules from within other modules:

```
import ( 
   "project_name/lib" 
)
```

or

```
import ( 
   "project_name/package_name" 
)
```

no need to `$ go init mod` in the subdirectories.